# Adding new action to devise registrations_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

my main devise route is:

```
devise_for :accounts,  :controllers => { :registrations => "users/accounts/registrations", :sessions => "accounts/devise/sessions" }, :class_name => 'Admin'
```

Then I want a new url/action so i add the following BEFORE the devise_for line above:

```
match '/accounts/signedup/' => 'users/accounts/registrations#signedup':
```

then in the controller i have the signedup action, but when i go to myurl.com/accounts/signedup which currently just has:

```
def signedup
    Rails.logger.debug { "&& signed_up" }
end
```

Then I go to myurl.com/accounts/signedup I get:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (AbstractController::ActionNotFound):
```

But if I remove the def signedup from the controller I instead get:

```
The action 'signedup' could not be found for Users::Accounts::RegistrationsController"
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution was:

```
devise_for :accounts,  :controllers => { :registrations => "users/accounts/registrations", :sessions => "accounts/devise/sessions" }, :class_name => 'Admin' do
  get "accounts/signedup", :to => "users/accounts/registrations#signedup", :as => "signedup_registration"
end
```

Comment: Per the devise docs recently: "Passing a block to devise_for is deprecated. Please remove the block from devise_for (only the block, the call to devise_for must still exist) and call devise_scope :user do ... end with the block instead."

Answer (score 21):

Your answer is correct, but the recent versions of devise have deprecated this behavior:

> Passing a block to devise_for is deprecated. Please remove the block from devise_for (only the block, the call to devise_for must still exist) and call devise_scope :user do ... end with the block instead.

Judging by what you have posted, in your case you should probably use `after_sign_in_path_for` in your custom RegistrationsController.

Here is what I used in my project as an alternative:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'session/on_signin', :to => 'sessions#memorize_session'
  end
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this answer, try devise_scope :user do if you are getting "Maybe you forgot" error messages when trying to use define_scope blocks.

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?

Comment: you need to use 'devise_scope :user do' not 'devise_scope :users do'

Comment: Thank you user2666194 and George - I changed it to 'devise_scope :user do'

Answer (score 7):

Using the following (make sure its not plural or you will get the error above).

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'session/on_signin', :to => 'sessions#memorize_session'
end
```

Then you can modify the devise_for as usual if you need to pass custom controllers.

devise_for :users

Comment: `devise_scope :user` or `devise_scope :users`?