# argument missing :controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Below is content of file and trace of error that I am facing. 
Line of code that is causing this error is in routes.rb

```
match 'users/set_up_details' => 'registrations#initialize_user_details', :via => post
```

controllers defined in my project

```
controllers
├── application_controller.rb
├── confirmations_controller.rb
├── notes_controller.rb
└── registrations_controller.rb
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :initialize_user_details, :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy ]
  def initialize_user_details
    # blah blah.....
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  NoteApp::Application.routes.draw do
  #match 'users/sign_up' => 'registrations#new'
  #match 'users' => 'registrations#create', :via => post
  #resources :registrations
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
                       :confirmations => "confirmations",
                       :registrations => "registrations"
                   }
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'notes#index'
    end
    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    end
  end
  match 'users/set_up_details' => 'registrations#initialize_user_details', :via => post # error caused by this line
  resources :notes


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

rake routes command error trace

```
>rake routes --trace

** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: missing :controller
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:174:in `default_controller_and_action'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:71:in `normalize_options!'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:61:in `initialize'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1315:in `new'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1315:in `add_route'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1294:in `decomposed_match'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1276:in `block in match'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1276:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1276:in `match'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:500:in `map_method'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:472:in `post'
/home/himanshu_office/projects/ruby_projects/note_app/config/routes.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:285:in `instance_exec'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:285:in `eval_block'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:263:in `draw'
/home/himanshu_office/projects/ruby_projects/note_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/himanshu_office/projects/ruby_projects/note_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/himanshu_office/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am overriding Devise controller. I need to define route as follows:

```
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'users/set_up_details' => 'registrations#initialize_user_details'
    end
```

Reference of solution:
[Adding new action to devise registrations_controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821126/adding-new-action-to-devise-registrations-controller)